# Parallax effect in viewpager tab bar

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to give parallax effect to viewpager title bar.
Something similar to what is done in this app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bitsie.playmee.musicplayer.free

How do I animate title as user swipe through viewpager?

I would really appreciate any help.

[image].

Comment: I tried implementing ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener and I know the code should go in onPageScrolled method but I'm not able to understand how to animate the view from there. I have created the titlebar to be a linearlayout

Comment: take a look at this: [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html). A better version of it (like playstore tabs) is [SlidingTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html). You will get lot of samples on GitHub.